# AWS Appflow just ingests few data from Google Analytics

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, google-analytics, amazon-appflow

I want to use Appflow to ingest data from Google Analytics, that track and store User's information and interaction data of some Website. I have never worked with Appflow or Google Analytics before, I found that Appflow worked quite weird and I don't know why, hope that somebody can give me some help or explanation:

1. On the Google Analytics Report Console, I can see that we have much customer data ~ 20K customer (users)
2. On the Appflow side, when I create flow, I selected some Object (or Field) from Source (GA) to ingest to S3, with ON-DEMAND trigger, WITHOUT any filter ,what i found is that:

   - If I select 3 fields: ga:userAgeBacket, ga:userGender, ga:interestOtherCatgory, the ouput on S3 Bucket ends up with ~1000 rows
   - If I select 3 fields above and add some addition fields like: ga:date, ga:day, ga:year, the output on S3 Bucket ends up with less data ~ 100 record

I have try a few times (with Schedule trigger and Full Load mode also) and the the result is still the same and I don't know whether in the first scenario, Appflow ingest all data or just ingest some of my data from GA either?
Thank you very much!